# javascript with Mongodb I need to get some information from the db in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am writing because I'm doing a program in Javascript and need to connect to MongoDB, I managed to get a tutorial and I can connect to the database and  insert elements, like:

```
var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
var collection = db.collection('documents');
 // Insert some documents
collection.insertMany([
{name: "Guns N' Roses", members: ['Axl Rose', 'Slash', 'Izzy Stradlin','Matt Sorum', 'Duff McKagan'], year: 1986}], function(err, result) {
assert.equal(err, null);
assert.equal(1, result.result.n);
assert.equal(1, result.ops.length);
console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the document collection");
callback(result);
});
}

var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
 // Get the documents collection
var collection = db.collection('documents');
 // Insert some documents
collection.find([], function(err, result) {
assert.equal(err, null);
console.log(result);
callback(result);
 });
}
```

with that I managed to insert code in the database, but now I need to extract information from the database and assign it to a variable for use in the rest of the Javascript code and I don't know how. Can you guys help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know which library you are using in node js, I usually use mongoose that is very intuitive to use.

Here's a link to the documentation that you can read

http://mongoosejs.com/

and for data on mongo, you have to do is this

```
collection.find(function (err, collection) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
    within the function you can do the searches you want,
    save them in variables and use then outside this function 
 console.log(collection);
})
```

if you realize it is very similar to what we already had in your example